# Access violation when trying to use std::vectors created by copying elements from an array

Tags: stdvector, access-violation, c++-cx

I'm working on a C++/CX DirectX project that is referenced in a UWP project.

The following function is part of the C++/CX project and is called from the UWP project at the start, mainly to create some meshes.

Everything was working fine until I changed so instead of having one `_trackMesh`, it's a `std::vector (_trackMeshes)` containing multiple meshes.
(basically I wanted to split up the mesh, with a max number of points per mesh).

But when I try to split the array containing all the points I get an access violation after setting the `localPlayerId` but before the end. I have no idea why.

Any help much appreciated.

Code:

```
IAsyncAction^ Track3DControl::InitializeAsync(const Array<TrackPoint>^ trackPoints, const Array<IPlayer^>^ players, int localPlayerId)
{
    _logger->Trace(L"InitializeAsync()");
    _isInitialized = false;

    Utilities::Copy(trackPoints, _trackPoints);

    int pointCount = trackPoints->Length;
    const int maxPointCount = 5000;
    int count = (int)ceil(pointCount / (double)maxPointCount);
    _logger->Error("_trackMeshes count: " + count);

    _trackMeshes = ref new Array<TrackMesh^>(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        _trackMeshes[i] = ref new TrackMesh(_logger, _d3dDevice, _d3dContext);
    }

    std::vector<task<void>> tasks;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int start = i * maxPointCount;
        int end = (i + 1)*maxPointCount;
        if (end > pointCount)
        {
            end = pointCount;// -1;
        }
        std::vector<TrackPoint> part(end);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < end-start; j++)
        {
            part[j] = _trackPoints[j+ start];
        }
        tasks.push_back(_trackMeshes[i]->InitializeAsync(&part));
    }

    for (auto index = 0u; index < static_cast<unsigned int>(_playerMeshes.size()); ++index)
    {
        tasks.push_back(_playerMeshes.at(index)->InitializeAsync(_playerModel.get()));
    }

    _localPlayerId = localPlayerId;

    return create_async([this, tasks]
    {
        return when_all(tasks.begin(), tasks.end()).then([this]
        {
            _isInitialized = true;

            _logger->Trace(L"Initialized.");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the vectors are correct before being send to the trackmeshes (*tasks.push_back(_trackMeshes[i]->InitializeAsync(&part));*),
but they were empty by the time the taks actually begins.

So I guess they go out of scope for some reason?

I stored the *part* vectors in a member variable (*std::vector> parts*)
and somehow that fixes everything.

If someone can explain this to me I'll mark that as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to access a local variable after it has been deleted. See here (other code removed):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    std::vector<TrackPoint> part(end); // <-- part created here

    tasks.push_back(_trackMeshes[i]->InitializeAsync(&part));

} // <-- part destroyed here
```

Every time around the loop you construct `part`, pass it's address to `InitializeAsync`, and then delete it. Whatever code you have running in the asynchronous part of `InitializeAsync` is going to be accessing deleted memory.